# Process large file in chunks or not

Tags: .net

I am processing a fairly large text file with over a million rows (50MB+) and then inserting into database using `SqlBulkCopy`.

So the process is: read file line by line -> populate `DataSet` -> insert using `SqlBulkCopy`.

For the file this size, should I split file processing into chunks instead loading the whole file into a `DataSet`? For example, populate `DataSet` only 100k rows at a time.

Comment: In my opinion it is better to upload by chunk. It it is important wrap whole process into transaction.

Comment: The correct answer to this is going to depend very much on your architecture.  How this piece fits into the overall solution, what kind of hardware its running on, what kind of network connection, how much memory is available, etc etc.  Way off topic for SO.