# c# importing large ASCII file to sql-server and breaking it down

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm currently tasked with importing 8 millions rows from an ASCII file to an SQL database.

I already formated the rows as an entity ready for manipulation but i can't find a way to break this enormous file into multiple DataTable to use with SQLBulkCopy...

Would you guys have any idea on how to proceed ? I'd like to use this solution [Process large file in chunks or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005258/process-large-file-in-chunks-or-not) but i don't know where to begin to start breaking my 1Go file down...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can read file line by line and insert the data line by line. This will take time but should't break the server

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi  It's already what i'm doing but it's no good. It takes more than 24h and the service is set to check for file and execute every 24h. Plus 8 millions SQL transaction is very unoptimised...

Comment: @Anas How is this a duplicate for your topic ? i'm trying to write a c# service to import an ASCII file; not use some tool to import a .sql file...

Comment: That is the problem that is is much easier to connect to the DB and write directly that writing to large files and then importing to db. That is why DBs where made

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi That's why i'm trying to break my file into multiple chunks then import them using SQLBulkCopy. The file wasn't written by me, it is a repertoire of all the streets in my country, it's emitted by the gov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, for the people who will have the same issue.
Just had to read each line then add it to a datable, once the DT is at batch size we send it then clear it for the next batch, at the end we send what's left even if datable is not at batch size :

```
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))


            using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream))


            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(bufferedStream))
            {
                string connectionString = @"connectionstring";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        dfdfdf = line.Substring(42, 1);
                        fdfdf = line.Substring(45, 1);

                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["dfdfdf"] = dfdfdf;
                        row["fdfdf"] = fdfdf;

                        dt.Rows.Add(row);

                        if (dt.Rows.Count == batchSize)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Batch sent");
                                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                                {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("dfdfdf", "dfdfdf");
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("fdfdf", "fdfdf");

                                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";
                                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                                }

                                dt.Clear();

                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Last batch sent");
                        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                        {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("dfdfdf", "dfdfdf");
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("fdfdf", "fdfdf");

                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                        }

                        dt.Clear();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

8M Rows is not that much with modern DBs and memory.

Have you looked at SSIS? It is really easy to import data from CSV to DB.

If you really need to use C# then you should be able to to build a data table in C# and then use Bulk Copy to load the data 
EG

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable("Test");

// Add column objects to the table. 
DataColumn ID = new DataColumn();

ID.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
ID.ColumnName = "Col1";
newTable.Columns.Add(ID);

 foreach ( row in your source)               
 {


            DataRow row = newTable.NewRow();
            row["col1"] = modified.ToString();
            newTable.Rows.Add(row);



 }

using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))            
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.test1";
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newTable);

        }
```

Comment: Yeah it has to be a c# service. Right now with 8M rows I estimated the import to 27h... I can't just fill one DT with my file cause "out of memory exception" that's why I was trying to fill multiples DT with a buffered stream.

Comment: So you can just change this pseudo code line: foreach ( row in your source) to be a Loop (eg 1-1M, 1M-2M etc) & put an outer loop for the number of times you want to run your bulk copy.